# Como puedo crear un input dentro de una clase en python (POO)

Tags: python, poo

Como estan, estoy aprendiendo python(POO) y estoy por hacer un proyecto pero necesito saber como hacer un input dentro de una clase, por ejemplo( una clase que sea para almacenar un nombre, necesito un inpuut en esa clase para poder ingresar el nombre.)

Comment: Hola @Ronny De la cruz, te invito a dar un tour hacia el manual de la pagina para poder crear una pregunta aceptada por la comunidad [tour]. según el manual esta pregunta no es apta así tal cual como esta, porfavor considera editarla o adaptarla para poder ayudarte, de lo contrario puede terminar cerrada, saludos!

Comment: Hola @Ronny De la cruz, considera revisar tu pregunta en este https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour, ya que haste este momento es candidata a terminar cerrada.